# How is a Quarterback's passer rating calculated in the NFL?

Tags: american-football, statistics, nfl

In the NFL, all of the stats like YPG, and average fantasy points are calculated somehow.
How is a passer's rating calculated?
Does it have something to do with the average yards gained per completion, or other countless QB statistics?
What is the formula that is used to calculate the passer rating?

Answer (score 8):

I'm not aware how fantasy points factor into a QB's passer rating.

That said, there are four separate calculations made with respect to passing values:

1. `((completions / attempts) - .3) * 5`
2. `((yards / attempts) - 3) * .25`
3. `(touchdowns / attempts) * 20`
4. `2.375 - ((interceptions / attempts) * 25)`

For each one, set the result to 2.375 if above that value, or set it to zero if negative.

Take these four calculations, divide the sum by six, and multiply by 100. And voila, the passer rating.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passer_rating#NFL_and_CFL_formula)